# WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.btorrent.xyz/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 522 {webtorrent}

Tags: webtorrent

Hello fellow homo sapiens, I seem to have reached a dead end here and would require your assistance. I am using webtorrent-hybrid to display a torrent, however when I use client.add to download my torrent, I get this error,

```
ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details 10
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://tracker.btorrent.xyz/.
```

and this is the code if you are curious,

```
client.add(torrentId, function (torrent) {

  var file = torrent.files.find(function (file) {
    return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
  })

  var info = torrent.ready
  console.log(info)
  file.appendTo('body')
  console.log(file)

  // Display the file by adding it to the DOM. Supports video, audio, image, etc. files

})
```

I would thankful if you could assist me in my problem.

Comment: [WebRTC say](https://webrtc.org/web-apis/firefox/) Firefox doesn't support TURN. Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: same issue here